# Difference between $P(A \cap B)$ and $P(A\mid B)$

Tags: probability

We are in a production process where products go through a production line from two different lines, in the process of production.

$A$ : event of going through line 1

$B$ : event of going through line 2

It's given that $P(A)=0.2$ and $P(B)=0.8$

Also these production lines might fail and produce defective goods.

$D$ : event of producing defective goods

Now look at the sentence below :

"Production line 1 suffered mechanical difficulty and produced 5% defectives."

Is this $P(D|A)$ or $P(D \cap B)$ I'm not looking for a  mathematical answer here. I'm looking for a intuition. $P(D|A)$ is the probability of being defective given $A$. We see here that $5$% of products produced from line 1 is defective. So Isn't this $P(D|A)$. But looking the other way around : $P(D \cap A)$ means probability of $D$ and $A$ happening together. If $5$% of products are defective in line 1, wouldn't this be $P(D \cap A)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(D|A)$ is the probability that D happens when we know for sure that A happens. Here we know that if a product goes through line 1 (ie if A), then we have 5% chance of it being deffective, thus $P(D|A) = 5\%$

$P(D\cap A)$  is the probability that given a product, it has gone through line 1 and is deffective.

Mathematically we have $P(D|A)P(A) = P(D\cap A)$, which one can see like this :
$P(D|A)$ is the probability of being deffective only considering products that have gone through line 1, whereas $P(D\cap A)$ is the probability of going through line 1 AND being deffective considering ALL products.

Answer (score 0):

Just read them as

- $\mathsf P(D\mid A)$ as "the probability for D *when* A happens."
- $\mathsf P(D\cap A)$ as "the probability for D *and* A happening."

> > "Production line 1 suffered mechanical difficulty and produced 5% defectives."

Can we rephrase this into one of the two forms above?   Yes, we can:

> The probability/rate for defectives *when* on production line 1 is $5\%$.

The statement did not tell us the probability for being defective *and* on line 1.  However, we can obviously find that out.
$$\mathsf P(A\cap D)~=~\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(D\mid A) ~=~0.2\times 0.05~=~0.01$$